# How does a "What is my IP" site know my internal LAN address?

Tags: networking

I'm staying in a hotel right now, and I wanted to see what my external IP address was. I visited a common site that helps with this, and it reported my address as ... (last few digits omitted for privacy)

> Your IP Address Is: 69.165.XXX.XXX
>
> Local Network IPs Detected: 10.1.XXX.XXX
>
> Possible Proxy Detected: 1.1 localhost:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)

The network IP is indeed the correct value. This confuses me because I don't think any browser would share this information. My guess is that the request header is being rewritten by Squid. In any event, this is a slightly bothersome privacy issue.

Comment: Possibly the X-Forwarded-For option on squid

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It uses a WebRTC method to gather your local ip:

> Firefox and Chrome have implemented WebRTC that allow requests to STUN servers be made that will return the local and public IP addresses for the user. These request results are available to javascript, so you can now obtain a users local and public IP addresses in javascript.

Source: https://github.com/vitalets/webrtc-ips
PoC: https://vitalets.github.io/webrtc-ips/demo/

**08/2019 update:** Currently PoC don't fully works because [Chrome added `mDNS` support to increase anonymity](https://bloggeek.me/psa-mdns-and-local-ice-candidates-are-coming/).

Answer (score -1):

When you visit a "What is my IP" website, the website is able to determine your internal LAN (Local Area Network) address by using JavaScript to retrieve the IP address assigned to your device by your router.

When you connect to a website, your device sends a request to the server hosting the website. The request contains information about your device, including your IP address. The website's server receives this request and can then use that information to determine your IP address and display it on the screen.

For Example; this website shows [What Is My IP Address? See Your Public Address, location, ISP, User agent, Device type](https://fgja.in/what-is-my-ip-address/)

Answer (score -4):

When you browse a webpage (such as whatismyip.com), your computer informs the server about your IP address so that server can send you back the HTML, graphics and other elements of the webpage you requested.

Consider following server variables (C# code):

```
string server = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]; 
string url = Request.ServerVariables["URL"]; 
querystring = Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]; 
string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (ipAddress == null || ipAddress == "")
{
    ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Following are some other variables:

```
"HTTP_X_COMING_FROM"
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" 
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED" 
"HTTP_X_REAL_IP" 
"HTTP_VIA" 
"HTTP_COMING_FROM" 
"HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR" 
"HTTP_FORWARDED" 
"HTTP_FROM" 
"HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION" 
"CLIENT_IP" 
"FORWARDED"
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is _not_ how HTTP request routing works. This is not the correct explanation for the issue in the question.